# Parsing JSON from array of arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, parsing

I have the following code that worked (past tense) great!

```
$(function() {
  var data = [{
    "day": "06/19/2016",
    "region": "Ohio",
    "metric": "98.61"
  }, {
    "day": "06/19/2016",
    "region": "Western NE",
    "metric": "98.63"
  }, {
    "day": "07/19/2016",
    "region": "Ohio",
    "metric": "68.61"
  }, {
    "day": "07/19/2016",
    "region": "Western NE",
    "metric": "32.63"
  }, {
    "day": "08/19/2016",
    "region": "Ohio",
    "metric": "98.61"
  }, {
    "day": "08/19/2016",
    "region": "Western NE",
    "metric": "48.63"
  }]

  var exist, index, options = {
    xAxis: {
      categories: []
    },
    series: []
  }
  Highcharts.each(data, function(p, i) {
    exist = false;
    if (options.xAxis.categories.indexOf(p.day) < 0) {
      options.xAxis.categories.push(p.day)
    }
    Highcharts.each(options.series, function(s, j) {
      if (s.name === p.region) {
        exist = true;
        index = j;
      }
    });
    if (exist) {
      options.series[index].data.push(parseFloat(p.metric))
    } else {
      options.series.push({
        name: p.region,
        data: [parseFloat(p.metric)]
      })
    }
  })
  $('#container').highcharts(options);
});
```

I have a fiddle for it here.... https://jsfiddle.net/wilkiejane/sr5dpaft/

Unfortunately vendor changed the format of the JSON and everything is broken and I'm not sure how to parse it.

It changed from [{},{},{}] to [[{}],[{}],[{}]]. Looks like several arrays now instead just one.

So now my data looks like this...

```
  var data = [[{
    "day": "06/19/2016",
    "region": "Ohio",
    "daily_er": "98.61"
  }],[{
    "day": "06/19/2016",
    "region": "Western NE",
    "daily_er": "98.63"
  }],[{
    "day": "07/19/2016",
    "region": "Ohio",
    "daily_er": "68.61"
  }],[{
    "day": "07/19/2016",
    "region": "Western NE",
    "daily_er": "32.63"
  }],[{
    "day": "08/19/2016",
    "region": "Ohio",
    "daily_er": "98.61"
  }],[{
    "day": "08/19/2016",
    "region": "Western NE",
    "daily_er": "48.63"
  }]
]
```

Does anyone know how I would iterate over this change? I'll keep banging away but so far I have spent a few hours on it with not much to show for it.

Comment: The simplest fix: add `p = p[0]` right after `Highcharts.each(data, function(p, i) {`.

Comment: Check this fiddle from juhana reference https://jsfiddle.net/eradi_singh/sr5dpaft/7/ coincidently i was working with sameview

Answer (score 2):

If you need the old format you may always convert the new format to the old one using Array.map().

```js
var data = [[{
  "day": "06/19/2016",
  "region": "Ohio",
  "daily_er": "98.61"
}],[{
  "day": "06/19/2016",
  "region": "Western NE",
  "daily_er": "98.63"
}],[{
  "day": "07/19/2016",
  "region": "Ohio",
  "daily_er": "68.61"
}],[{
  "day": "07/19/2016",
  "region": "Western NE",
  "daily_er": "32.63"
}],[{
  "day": "08/19/2016",
  "region": "Ohio",
  "daily_er": "98.61"
}],[{
  "day": "08/19/2016",
  "region": "Western NE",
  "daily_er": "48.63"
}]
];

//
// Convert new format to old format
//
data = data.map(function(ele, index) {
  return ele[0];
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: This of course assumes that the first element in each sub-arrays is all you care about. I'm not sure why the vendor would wrap each object in an array if there wasn't a chance that each sub-array could have more than one element. If there can be more than one item in a sub-array you might need to change the structure of your `each` loop instead. Depending on the meaning of each sub-array you might just be able to flatten the array using `reduce` and then process it the same way you used to.

Comment: @UselessCode You are right. But if i may permit, I suggest you to read comments where a fast solution was suggested: use p[0] instead of p in your loop. I'm sure the OP stopped on this. Moreover, there is this question about how to flatten arrays http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript   In any case thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the first element of each array by using `p[0]`, where the array is `p`. Of course, if you use that on your code you'd be assuming that each array does contain one element and you'd only be accessing the first element of each array.

A way to make it more "universal" and future-proof is to run a loop for each array. Check the working fiddle below:
https://jsfiddle.net/sr5dpaft/9/

I run a for loop through every element on each `p` array and do the logic for each existing element.